# Survivor function of a variable that has discrete and continuous components

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm currently reading The Statistical Analysis of Failure Time Data by Kalbfleisch and Prentice and had trouble at arriving at the expression for the survivor function of a random variable $T$ having both discrete and continuous components. The setup is the following:

Let $T$ be a random variable on $[0,\infty)$ with survivor function $F(t)=P(T>t)$. Then

- if $T$ is absolutely continuous with density $f$, then the hazard function $\lambda$ can be defined as 
  $$
  \lambda(t):=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{P(t\leq T<t+h\mid T\geq t)}{h}=\frac{f(t)}{F(t)}
  $$ for $t\geq 0$, and hence we have
  $$
  F(t)=\exp\left(-\int_0^t\lambda(s)\,\mathrm ds\right),\quad t\geq 0.
  $$
- if $T$ is discrete taking on the values $0\leq a_1<a_2<\cdots$, then we define the hazard at $a_i$ as
  $$
  \lambda_i=P(T=a_i\mid T\geq a_i),\quad i=1,2,\ldots.
  $$
  Then we can show that
  $$
  F(t)=\prod_{j\mid a_j\leq t}(1-\lambda_j),\quad t\geq 0.
  $$

These expressions for the survivor functions I am ok with. Now they write the following:

> More generally, the distribution of $T$ may have both discrete and continuous components. In this case, the hazard function can be defined to have the continuous component $\lambda_c(t)$ and discrete components $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$ at the discrete times $a_1<a_2<\cdots$. The overall survivor function can then be written
>   $$
> F(t)=\exp\left(-\int_0^t\lambda_c(s)\,\mathrm ds\right)\prod_{j\mid a_j\leq t}(1-\lambda_j).\tag{1}
> $$

That $T$ has both discrete and continuous components means that the distribution of $T$ is of the form
$$
P_T(\mathrm dx)=f_c(x) \lambda(\mathrm dx)+\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j \delta_{a_j}(\mathrm dx)
$$
or equivalently
$$
P(T\in A)=\int_A f_c(x)\,\mathrm dx+\sum_{j\mid a_j\in A} b_j
$$
for some sequence $a_1<a_2<\cdots$ and $b_i\in (0,1)$ and some non-negative measurable function $f_c$ with $\int_0^\infty f_c\,\mathrm d\lambda+\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_j=1$. If we define
$$
\lambda_c(t)=\frac{f_c(t)}{P(T\geq t)}=\frac{f_c(t)}{F(t)},\quad t\neq a_i,
$$
and
$$
\lambda_i=P(T=a_i\mid T\geq a_i),
$$
then how do I show (and is it even true) that the survivor function of $T$ is given by $(1)$?

Comment: I don't see an issue here: the authors consider relations between survivor function and hazard function separately for the case when there is density, and for the case when the distribution is purely discrete. In $(1)$ they combine the results for the distribution that has a continuous part and an purely discrete one. Now, for $t\neq a_j$ they define $\lambda_c(t) = f(t)/F(t)$, whereas for $t = a_j$ they use the second formula.

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks for the response. I guess my question is, what is the definition of a variable having both a continuous part and a purely discrete part?

Comment: Well, I don't think that in a measure-theory oriented course you would find a formal definition of it, but most likely they mean that the distribution $\mu_T$ of $T$ is given by
$$
  \mu_T(\mathrm dx) = f_c(x)\lambda(\mathrm dx) + \sum_{j}b_j \delta_{a_j}(\mathrm dx)
$$
where $f_c$ is some "sub-density" function, and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Ilya: That makes sense, but is it obvious that if $T$ has distribution given by $\mu_T$ above, and we define $\lambda_c$ according to $f_c$, and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$ according to $a_1,a_2,\ldots$, then its survivor function is given by $(1)$?

Comment: To be honest, in the current shape it is even not very obvious how do they define $\lambda_c$ and $\lambda_j$ in such a case.

Comment: @Ilya: I've edited the question, so that it's (hopefully) clear how $\lambda_c$ and $\lambda_j$ should be defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9377/discussion-between-ilya-and-stefan-hansen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $F(t) = \mathsf P(T>t) = 1-\mathsf P(T\leq t)$ is clearly of RCLL class on $[0,\infty)$. As a result, the definitions of continuous part of the hazard function $\lambda_c$ and discrete parts allow you computing $F$ by integrating $\lambda_c$ in between of the jumps, and applying jump conditions at $t = a_j$. The latter have the following shape:
$$
  \lambda_j = \mathsf P(T = a_j\mid T\geq a_j) = \frac{F(a_j-) - F(a_j)}{F(a_j-)}\implies F(a_j) = F(a_j-)(1-\lambda_j)
$$
where $F(t-):=\lim_{s\uparrow t}F(s)$.

Comment: Changed some $S$'s to $F$'s - hopefully it's what you intented to write. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @StefanHansen: thanks

Comment: Stefan what I don't understand is that in the book by Kalbfleisch and Prentice they define $F(t) = P(T \geq t)$ on page 6 instead of $F(t) = P(T > t)$ the way you define it. Hence in the denominator of the fraction in the post by @Ilya I fail to see how $P(T \geq a_j)$ can get turned to $\lim\limits_{t\to a_j^{-}}F(t)$ given the book's definition shouldn't it be just F(a_j). Which then raises the question, how did the authors get to the general survival function you quote in (1)? :S

Comment: Also their notation is horrible!!

Answer (score 1):

This may be very late but I would like to give my two cents on this question.

Suppose $\mu$ is a probability measure on $((0,\infty),\mathscr{B}((0,\infty))$ and let $F(x):=\mu(0,x]$. The ***Integrated Hazard Function*** $Q$ of $\mu$ is defined as
$$
Q(t)=\int_{(0,t]}\frac{1}{1-F(x-)}\mu(dx).
$$
The function $S(t):=1-F(t)$ is a right--continuous monotone nonincreasing function. $Q$ is a right--continuous monotone nondecreasing function whose associated (Lebesgue-Stieltjes) measure $\mu_Q\ll\mu$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_{Q}(\{x\})&=\Delta Q(x)=\frac{\Delta F(x)}{S(x-)}\\
\mu_{Q_c}(dx)&=\frac{1}{S(x-)}\mu_{F_c}(dx)\\
S(x-)\mu_Q(dx)&=\mu(dx)=\mu_F(dx).
\end{align}
$$
where $F_c$ and $Q_c$ is the continuous part of $F$ and $Q$ respectively. Then,
$Q$ and $F$ have the same points of discontinuity $\{x_j:j\in I\}$, and since $S(t)=1-F(t)=1-\int_{(0,t]}\mu(dx)$,
$$
\begin{align}
S(t)=S(0)-\int_{(0,t]}S(x-)\mu_Q(dx)\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$
We will show that $S$ is the unique solution to $\eqref{one}$ that is bounded in any bounded set, and that
$$
S(t)=\exp\big(-Q_c(t)\big)\prod_{0<x_j\leq t}
(1-\Delta Q(x_j)).
$$

---

The proof of this will be a consequence of the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $F$ be a right--continuous  monotone nondecreasing function in $[0,\infty)$ and let $\mu_F$ be the unique measure on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\mu\big((a,b]\big)=F(b)-F(a)$. Let $\{x_j:j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be the sequence of all discontinuities of $F$. If $v\in\mathcal{L}^{loc}_1(\mu_F)$ then,  for any  number $H_0\geq0$ the function
$$
\begin{align}
H(t)=H_0\exp\Big(\int_{(0,t]}v(x)\mu_{F_c}(dx)\Big)\prod_{0<x_j\leq t}(1+v(x_j)\Delta F(x_j))\tag{2}\label{expo-form}
\end{align}
$$
is the unique solution in $t\geq0$ of the integral equation
\begin{align}
\label{integro-exp}
H(t)=H(0)+\int_{(0,t]}H(x-)v(x)\mu_F(dx)
\end{align}
satisfying $\|H\mathbb{1}_{(0,t]}\|_u<\infty$ for all $t>0$.

---

The formula quoted in the OP is $\eqref{one}$, and existence and uniqueness are obtained by the Theorem above with $v\equiv-1$.

---

Since formula $\eqref{expo-form}$ appears often in applications Survival analysis and reliability theory, I think I is worthwhile to present a proof. This will be based entirely on Lebesgue integration by parts.

**Preliminary notation:**

For any real valued function $F$ on an interval $I$, denote by $\mu_F$ the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by $F$, so $\mu_F\big((a,b]\big)=F(b)-F(a)$ for all $[a,b]\subset I$.

- [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3724004/121671) that for any real valued functions $F$, $G$ of local finite variation in some interval $I$
  $$
  \int_{(a,b]} F(t)\,\mu_G(dt)=F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)-\int_{(a,b]}G(t-)\,\mu_F(dt)
  $$
  for all $[a,b]\subset I$. This formula may be denoted as
  $$
  d(FG)=F\,dG+ G_-\,dF
  $$
  where $G_-(t):=G(t-)$ and $dF(x):=\mu_F(dx)$, that is $dF\big((a,b]\big)=F(b)-F(a)$.
- If $G$ is a continuous function of locally finite variation, then
  $$ dG^n = n G^{n-1}(t)\,dG$$
  This can be shown by induction. For $n=1$ is valid. For $n\geq1$
  $$ d(G^{n+1})=d(G^n\,G)=G\,dG^n + G^n\,dG=nG^n\,dG+ G^n\,dG=(n+1) G^n\,dG$$
  From this, we obtain the well known exponential formula for continuous measures:
  $$\begin{align}
   d e^G(t) = e^{G(t)}\,dG(t):= e^{G(t)}\,d\mu_G(dt)\tag{3}\label{exp-for1}
  \end{align}
  $$

**A technical result:**

**Lemma:**
Suppose $G$ is right--continuous nondecreasing  in the interval $[0,T)$ $(0<T\leq\infty)$. Then, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
\int_{(0,t]}G^{n-1}(s-)\mu_G(ds)\leq \frac{G^n(t)-G^n(0)}{n}\leq\int_{(0,t]}G^{n-1}(s)\mu_G(ds)
$$
for all $0<t<T$. (In differential notation,  $nG^{n-1}_-dG\leq dG^n\leq nG^{n-1}dG$.)

*Here is a short proof*:

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $G^n$ is right--continuous an nondecreasing and so, the associates Lebesgue--Stieltjes measure $\mu_{G^n}$ is nonnegative. Repeated application of integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
  dG^n &= G^{n-1}_-\,dG + G\,dG^{n-1}=G^{n-1}_-\,dG + G (G^{n-2}_-\,dG + G\,dG^{n-2})\\
  &= (G^{n-1}_-+GG^{n-2}_- +\ldots + G^{n-1})\,dG
\end{align}
$$
in differential notation. As $G(s-)\leq G(s)$ for all $0<s\leq T$, we conclude that
$$
n G^{n-1}_-\,dG \leq dG^n\leq n G^{n-1}\,dG
$$

**Proof of main Theorem:**

As $v\in \mathcal{L}^{loc}_1(\mu_F)$, $v\in\mathcal{L}^{loc}_1(\mu_{F_I})$, and so
$$
\|v\mathbb{1}_{(0,t]}\|_{\mathcal{L}_1(\mu_{F_I})}=\sum_{0<x_j\leq t}|v(x_j)|\Delta F(x_j)<\infty.
$$
Consequently $H$ is bounded on each compact subinterval of $[0,\infty)$.
Let
$$
\begin{align}
G_1(t)&=H_0\prod_{0<x_j\leq t}(1+v(x_j)\Delta F(x_j))\\
G_2(t)&=\exp\Big(\int_{(0,t]}v(x)\mu_{F_c}(dx)\Big).
\end{align}
$$
$G_1$ is right--continuous pure jump function of bounded variation which changes  only at $x_j$; moreover,
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta G_1(x_j)=G(x_j)-G(x_j-)&=G(x_j-)\big(1+v(x_j)\Delta F(x_j)\big)-G(x_j-)\\
&= G(x_j-)v(x_j)\Delta F(x_j).
\end{align}
$$
$G_2$ is a continuous  monotone nondecreasing function and
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_{G_2}(dx)&=\exp\Big(\int_{(0,x]}v(y)\mu_{F_c}(dy)\Big)v(x)\mu_{F_c}(dx)\\
&= G_2(x)v(x)\mu_{F_c}(dx).
\end{align}
$$
Applying the integration by parts formula to $H(t)=G_1(t)G_2(t)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
H(t)-H(0)&=\int_{(0,t]}G_1(x-)\mu_{G_2}(dx)+\int_{(0,t]}G_2(x)\mu_{G_1}(dx)\\
&= \int_{(0,t]}G_1(x-)G_2(x)v(x)\mu_{F_c}(dx)+
\sum_{0<x_j\leq t}G_2(x_j)G_1(x_j-)v(x_j)\Delta F(x_j)\\
&= \int_{(0,t]}H(x-)v(x)\mu_{F_c}(dx)+\int_{(0,t]}H(x-)v(x)\mu_{F_I}(dx)\\
&=\int_{(0,t]}H(x-)v(x)\mu_F(dx).
\end{align}
$$
It remains to prove uniqueness. Suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two solutions and set $D=H_1-H_2$. Let $M:=\|D\mathbb{1}_{(0,t]}\|_u$ and $\Lambda(t)=\int_{(0,t]}|v(x)|\mu_F(dx)$. Then,
$$
|D(t)|\leq \int_{(0,t]}|D(x-)||v(x)|\mu_F(dx)\leq M\int_{(0,t]}|v(x)|\mu_{F}(dx)
= M\Lambda(t).
$$
As $\Lambda$ is nondecreasing and right continuous, $|D(x-)| \leq M\Lambda(x-)$. By the technical Lemma above
$$
\begin{align}
|D(t)|&\leq M\int_{(0,t]}\Lambda(x-) |v(x)|\mu_F(dx) = M\int_{(0,t]}\Lambda(x-)\mu_\Lambda(dx)\leq \frac{M}{2} \Lambda^2(t).
  \end{align}
$$
Continuing by induction we obtain
$|D(t)|\leq \frac{M}{n!}\Lambda^n(t)$. Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ gives $|D(t)|=0$.