# Let $(a,b)$ and $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(a,b)$. For $x_0\in (a,b)$, $F(t)=\int_{x_0}^{t}f(s)ds$. Prove that, $DF=f$ (towards theoretical distribution).

Tags: lp-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $(a,b)$ and $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(a,b)$. For $x_0\in (a,b)$, consider
$$
F(t)=\int_{x_0}^{t}f(s)ds.
$$
Prove that, $DF=f$ (towards theoretical distribution).

I thought of the following: Let $\varphi$, we had
$$
\left\langle DF, \varphi \right\rangle = \left\langle F, \dfrac{d}{dx}\varphi \right\rangle=\int_a^bF(x)\dfrac{d}{dx}\varphi (x)dx = \int_a^b \int_{x_0}^xf(s)ds\dfrac{d}{dx}\varphi (x)dx...
$$
but it leads to nothing. I also thought about,
$$
\left| \left\langle DF, \varphi \right\rangle - \left\langle f, \varphi \right\rangle \right| = \left| \left\langle F, \dfrac{d}{dx}\varphi \right\rangle - \left\langle f, \varphi \right\rangle \right|=\int_a^bF\dfrac{d}{dx}\varphi-\int_a^bf\varphi...
$$

Comment: $F$ is  absolutely continuous (in any compact set)  differentiable at any Lebesgue point of $f$ and hence a.s. Thus [Lebesgue integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3724004/121671) by parts works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume that $f$ is continuous. Then $F$ is $C^1$ and $F' = f$. Also
\begin{align}
-\int_a^b F(x) \varphi'(x) dx &=\int_a^b F'(x)  \varphi(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x) \varphi (x)dx.
\end{align}

Thus $DF = f$ in the distribution sense. Now for any $f\in L^1_{loc}(a, b)$ and any test function $\varphi$, let $I \subset (a, b)$ be a compact interval which contains the support of $\varphi$ and $x_0$. Let $\{f_n\} \in L^1(a, b)$ be a sequence of continuous functions to converges to $f$ in $L^1(I)$. Let $F_n(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f_n (t) dx$. One can check that $F_n$ converges to $F$ in $L^1(I)$. Thus

\begin{align}
 -\int_a^b F(x) \varphi'(x) dx &= -\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b F_n(x) \varphi'(x) dx \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b F'_n(x) \varphi(x) dx \\ 
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x) \varphi(x) dx \\
&=\int_a^b f(x) \varphi(x) dx. 
\end{align}

Thus $DF = f$ also in the distribution sense.