# Integration by Parts for a Complex Measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu$ a complex (Radon) measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$. Why is it true that
$$\int f d\mu=\int f'(x)F(x)dx$$
Folland suggests that one should use the integration by part formula (Theorem 3.36 on his Real Analysis), but I did not see how it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question?(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3724004/121671)

Comment: Could you say the theorem /exercise number where that statement is found in Folland's book?