# Hazard Function for Discrete RV from General Definition

Tags: probability

Given a random variable $T>0$ (time to event), I am using the following (general?) definition of the hazard function:
$$
\lambda(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(t\leq T < t + h \ | \ T \geq t)}{h}
$$
according to [this textbook](https://link-springer-com.proxy.uba.uva.nl/book/10.1007/b97377).
In this same text they split the continuous and discrete cases. For the continuous case they claim
$$
\lambda(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}
$$
where $f$ is the density and $S=1-F$ is the survival function. I derived this by
\begin{aligned}
       \lambda(t) 
       &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(t\leq T < t + h\ | \ T \geq t)}{h} \\\\ 
&= \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(T\geq t)} \cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(T<t+h)-\mathbb{P}(T<t)}{h} \\\\
       &= \frac{1}{S(t)}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h} \\\\
       &= \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}
\end{aligned}
where we use the fact that strict and non-strict inequalities provide equal probabilities for continuous variables, and the definition of the derivative of the CDF.

However, I cannot seem to derive the simpler form for the discrete case ($T\in \{t_0,t_1,\dots \}$) in a similar fashion. It should become
$$
\lambda(t_j) = \mathbb{P}(T=t_j \ | \ T\geq t_j) = \frac{p_j}{S(t_{j-1})}
$$
where $p_j=\mathbb{P}(T=t_j)$. It makes a lot of sense and looks like a complete parallel to the continuous case, where now the division by the survival function is slightly different (1 time point behind) as in the discrete case, strict and non-strict inequalities do change matters slightly.
When I try the following, it doesn't seem to work.
\begin{align}
    \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(t_j\leq T < t_j+h \ | \ T\geq t_j)}{h} 
    &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(t_j\leq T < t_j+h)}{\mathbb{P}(T\geq t_j)\cdot h} \\\\
    &= \frac{1}{S(t_{j-1})}\cdot \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\mathbb{P}(T < t_j+h)-\mathbb{P}(T < T_j)}{h}
\end{align}
From this it isn't so clear to me how to go to the PMF, as it was to get to the CDF/density in the continuous case. If I write (for small $h$, such that $t_j+h<t_{j+1}$)
$$
\mathbb{P}(t_j\leq T < t_j+h) = \mathbb{P}(T = t_j) = p_j
$$
it becomes
$$
\lambda(t_j) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{p_j}{S(t_{j-1})\cdot h}
$$
which the $h$ in the denominator blows up into $+\infty$. I think in this latter assumption for small $h$, it should perhaps somehow cancel the $h$ in the denominator so that the limit does not explode to $+\infty$.

Any ideas on how to get to the right conclusion, with the right steps? Am I missing something, or is the first 'general' definition of the hazard function only used for continuous variables, and the second outcome for the discrete case simply a separate definition of the hazard rate, which requires no proof?

Comment: For general distributions (continuous or deterministic)one can define the integrated hazard function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428938/121671)